# Implementing a stack (LIFO) in SQL Server using stored procs/functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking at writing a stack (LIFO) implementation in SQL Server. I would like to have a function that pushes a string onto the stack, a function that would pop the string off the stack and a function that gets the current value on the stack. So far am looking at using IDENTITY to keep track of stacks but does anyone have a better implementation or some hints on how to implement this in sql server?

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity... why would you want to do this?

Comment: it's a third party software and my only way to customize is SQL. No CLR, no .NET.

Comment: See the LIFO Stacks section here http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/

Comment: @MartinSmith: You should submit that as an answer - that is a great site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a table like this:

```
create table Stack(id int not null identity primary key, value nvarchar(max))
```

Push:

```
insert into Stack (value) values ('pushed value')
```

Peek:

```
select top 1 value from Stack order by id desc
```

Pop:

```
declare @id int, @value nvarchar(max)
select top 1 @id=id, @value=value from Stack order by id desc
if @id is null begin
  -- handle stack-underflow here
end
delete from Stack where id=@id
select @value
```

It's not strictly a stack internally, because SQL Server has to do an index scan in order to get the most recently added item, instead of just using a stack pointer.

However, from my testing, it appears that SQL Server is smart and does the scan "backwards", and therefore only hits one row anyway. Therefore, practically speaking all operations are O(1).

Comment: With the pop in my answer?

Comment: no, I had a problem implementing my own pop. Yours looks good.